# GoogleMap moveCamera/animateCamera not working

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-5.0-lollipop

I've got a map inside a fragment. I'm trying to move the camera to a specific position (on global layout):

```
@Override
public void onGlobalLayout() {
    getMapView().getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
            LocationManager.onLocation(new CoordinatesCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCoordinates(double latitude, double longitude) {
                    LatLng target = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                    CameraPosition position = CameraPosition
                            .builder()
                            .target(target)
                            .zoom(10)
                            .build();
                    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(position);
                    googleMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

`getMapView()` returns my map view, the latitude/longitude are perfectly valid (typed them into maps, it's my home), tried both `moveCamera` and `animateCamera`, tried `newLatLngZoom` method too, but no avail.  All I'm getting is an empty map view:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:** I've got other maps in various parts of my app, and they work just fine.

Comment: try to pass float value like this `.zoom(10.0f)` i hope it will work.

Comment: @HardikVasani It won't have any difference: the zoom method has only one overload: `zoom(float)`, and passing an int `10` will automatically be casted to float `10.f` in compile time. `zoom(10)` and `zoom(10.f)` are identical.

Comment: `googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(new CameraPosition.Builder().target(LatLng).zoom(14.0f).build()));` this work for me.  and one more thing i have a no idea `hardwareaccelerated` property playing in role in this issue if add this property in your manifest file so remove and try this.

Comment: @HardikVasani I have the exact same pattern, but not working. I've also forced software rendering (disabling hardware acceleration), but no avail.

Comment: if you resolved this issue please share ans with us Thank you!.

Comment: @HardikVasani I will. Just caught something, I'm on it.

Comment: @HardikVasani posted my answer.

Comment: great job thanx for your response!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177859/discussion-between-hardik-vasani-and-can-poyrazoglu).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem had nothing to do with the camera. I was using `MapView` inside a fragment, which apparently isn't supported. I've changed `MapView` to `MapFragment` and it worked. It's absolutely ridiculous that Google just creates the map and it stays blank silently with a logo, instead of throwing an exception in case of this unsupported scenario.